# RFCs & IANA specs about Ed25519 inaccurate?

Tags: public-key, terminology, ed25519, standards, eddsa

While designing a crypto system based on existing standards and specifications i find myself questioning some of the accuracy in the current RFC-8037 and IANA specs around Edwards curves, 25519 and ed25519 notation

In [RFC8037](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8037#appendix-A), they say that the public key in its compressed form (32 bytes) should be represented by **X**. But in Edwards curves, unlike Montgomery (Curve25519) shouldn't be **Y** with a signed bit for **X** instead?

Another thing that's odd is that on both RFC and [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jose/jose.xhtml#web-key-elliptic-curve) they put ed25519 in the elliptic curve section. But technically it's a signing scheme not a curve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But in Edwards curves, unlike Montgomery (Curve25519) shouldn't be Y
> with a signed bit for X instead?

Yes

> In RFC8037, they say that the public key in its compressed form (32
> bytes) should be represented by X

They call it `x` in the JSON representation, which I agree is confusing. However, I've checked their example private key `9d61b19deffd5a60ba844af492ec2cc44449c5697b326919703bac031cae7f60`. If you hash that with SHA-512, clamp it, scalar multiply it with the base point, extract the y co-ordinate of the resulting point, and apply the sign bit if necessary, the answer is identical to the hex public key example they list in the appendix.

I suspect their reasoning is that when `x` and `y` are specified, they really are co-ordinates of an EC point. However, when using 'point compression' to represent the point in a single 32-byte sequence, strictly speaking it's no longer a `y` co-ordinate because of the sign-bit manipulation. So I'm guessing they just decided to always place a compressed point representation in the `x` field and leave the `y` field empty (regardless of which of the two co-ordinates the compressed point representation was derived from).

> Another thing that's odd is that on both RFC and IANA they put ed25519
> in the elliptic curve section. But technically it's a signing scheme
> not a curve?

People commonly refer to both the signature scheme and to the curve itself as Ed25519. Monero, for example, uses the Ed25519 curve but not the Ed25519 signature scheme.